A title in a textblock is going over the margins
first question here, sorry if not proper enough, but I'll try to give you the necessary informations. I've downloaded a template for a thesis (I'm using luaTeX), which uses textblock to (I think, cause I'm still learning TeX) encapsulate specific parts of the text in order for it to stay in place. The problem is that the title of the thesis goes over the margins, and I don't know what to change in order to make it go to a new line.

What I have is:
\begin{textblock*}{21cm}(0cm,13.66cm)
    \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
    \centerline {\textbf{Il trattamento della sindrome autistica in          ottica psicoanalitica}}
\end{textblock*}

and I'm working in:
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}

Here to add every possible information needed, thanks in advance

you should provide an example that shows the problem. You have shown a fragment of code loading book class but that does not define an enviornment called textblock* so you presumably have some code that defines that somewhere,

Why \centerline? And why \textblock?

With textblock* in your example the reference point for the positioning argument denoting the location of the top left corner of the block is the reference point of the surrounding box.
In your case the surrounding box probably is a horizontal box holding a line of the page.
With the following example it is the box holding the very first line of the page and as that line/box contains only the textblock*, its reference point goes on the top left corner of the type block.
So outgoing from the top left corner of the paper

the vertical position of the first line of text's textblock*s' top left corners is
1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\voffset+⟨vertical component of textblock*'s positioning argument⟩.
the horizontal position of the first line of text's textblock*s' top left corners is 1in+\evensidemargin/\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+⟨horizontal component of textblock*'s positioning argument⟩.

Usually \hoffset and \voffset are 0pt and usually you don't take them into account so that they can be used for shifting entire pages if for some reason this is needed with the printing machines in use.
Due to the asynchronity of the output routine you need to place a zref-referencing-label into the textblock for storing the number of the page where the textblock occurs. This way you can find out if the textblock is on a recto or on a verso page which is needed for deciding whether \oddsidemargin or \evensidemargin needs to be taken into account with the calculation of the textblock's horizontal position.
So all in all probably s.th. like
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[abspage]{zref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\saveabspage[1]{\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{abspage}}
\newcommand*\getabspage[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{abspage}{-1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Horizontal centering inside the margins/inside the typeblock of the page:
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0cm,13.66cm)%
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
  \noindent
  \parbox{\hsize}{%
    \centering
    \textbf{%
      \strut
      Il trattamento della sindrome autistica in ottica psicoanalitica%
      \strut
    }%
  }%
\end{textblock*}
%
% Horizontal centering on the paper:
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(%
  -\dimexpr
     1in+
     \ifodd\getabspage{Unique name of this textblock}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi
   \relax,%
  18.66cm%
)%
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
  \noindent
  \parbox{\hsize}{%
    \saveabspage{Unique name of this textblock}%
    \centering 
    \textbf{%
      \strut
      Il trattamento della sindrome autistica in ottica psicoanalitica%
      \strut
    }%
  }%
\end{textblock*}

\noindent TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT

\end{document}

might do the trick.


Probably you can do without textpos, just doing appropriate horizontal kerning:
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[abspage]{zref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\saveabspage[1]{\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{abspage}}
\newcommand*\getabspage[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{abspage}{-1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT\hfill TEXT

\bigskip

% Horizontal centering inside the margins/inside the typeblock of the page:
\noindent
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
  \centering
  \textbf{%
    \strut
    Il trattamento della sindrome autistica in ottica psicoanalitica%
    \strut
  }%
}%


\bigskip

% Horizontal centering on the paper:
\noindent
\rlap{%
  \kern-\dimexpr
          1in+
          \ifodd\getabspage{Unique name of this textblock}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi
        \relax
  \parbox{\paperwidth}{%
    \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
    \centering
    \saveabspage{Unique name of this textblock}%
    \textbf{%
      \strut
      Il trattamento della sindrome autistica in ottica psicoanalitica%
      \strut
    }%
  }%
}%

\end{document}



Thank you very much, I'm not sure if what I did is the proper solution, but adding the package you suggested in the environment and then changing the cm numbers in the textblock sections allowed me to place the (now two-lined) title at the center of the page.
